# Spring MVC rest services 400 bad request for some calls

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I have a Spring mvc app and I also have rest services for some functionalities. It was working fine till last week, but suddenly some of the calls are having issues.

I noticed all of these calls are of type "method = RequestMethod.PUT" functions. I get the following error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:382)
```

My Controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user/a2")
public class ABCController {

    @Autowired
    private ABCServices       ABCServices;


     @RequestMapping(
                value  = "user/{userName}/checkTest",
                method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST} -----------------this call works fine
        )
        public @ResponseBody
        String check(@PathVariable String userName) {


     }

     @RequestMapping(
                value  = "user/{userName}/validateABCSS",  
                method = RequestMethod.PUT
            )
            public @ResponseBody 
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> validateABCSS(@PathVariable String userName, @RequestBody AAA uSS) {
                -----------------this call does not work


                if ("Success".equals(result)) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.OK);
                } else {
                    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(result.getBytes(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
}
```

RestClient.java,

```
public class RestClient {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String       UN;
    private String       serverUrl;

    public RestClient() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    public RestClient(String pServerUrl, String key, String sec, String pUN) {



        ClientHttpRequestInterceptor tokenAuthInterceptor = new TokenAuthHeaderRequestInterceptor(key,sec, pUN);

        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(tokenAuthInterceptor));

        SSLContext sslContext = null;

        try {
            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).useTLS().build();
        }  catch (Exception e) {

        }

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, 
                new String[]{"SSLv2Hello","SSLv3", "TLSv1"}, null, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());


        HttpClient               httpClient     =
            HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    }

    public enum ServiceURLs {

        VALIDATE_ABCSS("user/a2/user/{userName}/validateABCSS"), CheckTest("user/a2/user/{userName}/checkTest");

        private String id;
        private String url;

        private ServiceURLs(String id) {
            this.id  = id;
            this.url = id;
        }

        private ServiceURLs(String id, String url) {
            this.id  = id;
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getId() {

            return this.id;
        }

        public String getUrl() {

            return this.url;
        }
    }


    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return this.restTemplate;
    }
}
```

I call the template as below

```
getRestTemplate().put(serverUrl + RestClient.ServiceURLs.VALIDATE_ABCSS.getUrl(), pObject, getLogin()).
```

The only thing I did was to config SSL, but now changed them back to old state(though the  keystores has the keys). I am even using the URLS with only http. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

The setup: my app is in tomcat, rest services app is in weblogic, the authentication happens via custom app(keys and secret).

Comment: Debug and figure out the value of 'result'. Also, What is the datatype, logic to get the value for this variable ? Its clear from your code that you could be hitting the else portion while checking the value of this variable

Answer (score 0):

May be result is coming as false.
Check what is reason for result value is "false".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already updated the else loop with a different http status and still got the same 400 response. The issue is I do not even see the request coming to this method. I have some log statements and they are not printed in the logs. Thanks.